# DynamicEnumProperty provider class that implements IDynamicEnumValuesProvider not being loaded by Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vsx, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

Hello I have a managed package that provides the code for a custom C++ build toolchain. I have a custom platform Toolset.targets that loads some custom properties:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)projprops.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

projprops.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rule Name="MyGeneralProperties"
  Order="9"
  DisplayName="MyRule"
  Description="General"
  PageTemplate="generic"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/build/2009/properties">
    <Rule.Categories>
        <Category Name="General" DisplayName="General" Description="General" />
    </Rule.Categories>
    <Rule.DataSource>
        <DataSource Persistence="UserFile"/>
    </Rule.DataSource>

    <DynamicEnumProperty Name="BuildMachine" DisplayName="Build Machine" Category="General" EnumProvider="BuildMachines" Visible="True" Description="The machine that building and debugging will take place on."/>
</Rule>
```

I have my enum provider in the same DLL as the package and it looks like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDynamicEnumValuesProvider))]
[DynamicEnumCategory("BuildMachines")]
public class BuildMachineEnumProvider : IDynamicEnumValuesProvider
{
    // the implementation
}
```

An instance of `BuildMachineEnumProvider` is never created by the runtime however the property shows up in the VC project properties right where it's supposed to. The package loads as it should when a solution is loaded via `[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]`. According to everything I've read MEF should recognize my enum provider class when the package is loaded and everything else should just work - except it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark your VSPackage as MEF-enabled.

Check for details here: [Does anyone know how to implement the DynamicEnumProperty type for C++ Project Property rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090422/does-anyone-know-how-to-implement-the-dynamicenumproperty-type-for-c-project-p/29291231#29291231)

Comment: That worked! My package was by default, in the vsixmanifest, set to Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage, switching it to Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent solved the problem. Thanks!